# So Im getting some of the code to work, just my call to the function for getting the average of the test scores isnt working i dont know what to pass

Tags: python

```
def determine_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:       
        return 'A'
    elif score >= 80:
        return 'B'
    elif score >= 70:
        return 'C'
    elif score >= 60: 
        return 'D'
    else:
        return 'F'


def calc_average(test1, test2, test3, test4, test5):
    avg = sum((test1, test2, test3, test4, test5))/5
    return avg

def main():
    
    test1 = int(input('Enter score 1: '))
    test2 = int(input('Enter score 2: '))
    test3 = int(input('Enter score 3: '))
    test4 = int(input('Enter score 4: '))
    test5 = int(input('Enter score 5: '))
    
    print('Average of the Test Scores')
    print()
    print(f'{"score":>5}{"numeric grade":>20}{"letter grade":>15}')
    print('----------------------------------------')
    test1_score = determine_grade(test1)
    print(f'{"score 1:":<5}{50:>10}{test1_score:>15}')
    test2_score = determine_grade(test2)
    print(f'{"score 2:":<5}{50:>10}{test2_score:>15}')
    test3_score = determine_grade(test3)
    print(f'{"score 3:":<5}{50:>10}{test3_score:>15}')
    test4_score = determine_grade(test4)
    print(f'{"score 4:":<5}{50:>10}{test4_score:>15}')
    test5_score = determine_grade(test5)
    print(f'{"score 5:":<5}{50:>10}{test5_score:>15}')
    
    
main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

You should call the method, just like the other function that you are calling.

line 26 of your code:

```
# ...
print('Average of the Test Scores')
avg_score = calc_average(test1, test2, test3, test4, test5)
print(avg_score)
# ...
```